# Why is Typescript complaining about a possible undefined value when I'm checking if the value is defined in a previous line?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code, I'm wondering why Typescript is complaining, the function isNextWeek expects a string and here the code complains that argument of type string or undefined is not assignable, but aren't I checking for the localTime being defined in the localTimeExists check - so it should never call the function if it's undefined.

Not sure why it's complaining, or if anyone has suggestions to avoid this issue. I did manage to avoid it by wrapping it in an 'if' condition but then that scopes the value to that block and I want to use it outside so wondered if there is another way. Thanks

```js
const localTimeExists = !!out && !!out.localTime;
const doThis = !isToday && localTimeExists && isNextWeek(out.localTime);
```

Comment: Typescript won't propagate the conditional information through the `localTimeExists` variable - that just has type `boolean`. If you inline that, it should work.

Comment: Adding an exclamation point at the end of the variable would be an alternative solution, i.e. `isNextWeek (out.localTime!)`

Comment: @Bergi I did do it inline but wanted to make the code more readable and neater so thought I'd extract the condition into a variable. So what you mean is that in the second line, the function isNextWeek doesn't recognise that out.localTime has a value from the check on the first line?

Comment: @MattBrowne what does the exclamation mark do? It worked when I added it twice, once after 'out' and then again after 'localTime' like this - out!.localTime!. I don't think it looks good though for some reason.

Comment: @jobe It's about the conditional `&&` or `if`. If on the left side / in the condition `out.localTime` was checked for truthiness, typescript will know that `out.localTime` won't be `undefined` on the right hand side / in the body. It won't do that inference if you're checking the `localTimeExists` variable only.

Comment: One side comment @Bergi - I managed to make it inline in the end but if you had a deeply nested object and you had to do this truthy check inline, it would look quite messy wouldn't it? What would you do in that case?

Comment: Consider editing this question's title to be more descriptive, as mentioned in [ask].

Comment: @jobe I'd probably use nullish coaleascing, and possibly make `isNextWeek` accept `undefined`/`null` and just have it return `false`. Then it'll be `const doThis = !isToday && isNextWeek(out?.localTime)`

Comment: @jcalz done, hope this is better

Comment: @Bergi nice suggestion

Comment: @jobe The `!` at the end of a variable name is the "non-null assertion operator". It can be used in cases where you're sure you know better than the compiler that a variable will never be null. Obviously it has to be used with care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing @Bergis comment which worked for me - I got this to work by bringing the truthy check inline, as extracting it into a separate line confused Typescript in making the inference.